# how to load two images with Lazyloading in one cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application I have used Lazyloading for displaying image from url. But now i want to display two multiple images in one cell. How can i do this please help me.

Comment: what you have tried and what is the issue?

Comment: @ Pooja M. Bohora i have only display the single image.

Comment: What you have used for lazy loading?

Comment: Create two imageview Object in custom cell. gave them frame , add in cell's subview.then for download use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for download image.

Comment: @ Pooja M. Bohora https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html. i follow this code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. add this code in cellfor row and for Download Image use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
UIImageView *imgView1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView1.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);//Your Frame
imgView1.image = [UIImage ImageNamed:@"a"]; // your image or download image code or use Sdwebimage
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];

UIImageView *imgView2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgView2.frame=CGRectMake(25,0,25,25);//Your Frame
imgView2.image = [UIImage ImageNamed:@"b"]; // your image or download image code or use Sdwebimage
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView2];
```

If you want to add more images then add same code and just give frame.

Comment: sry bro i taken ur sample

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Cant understand.